# add meta tag on Iframe parent head element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have need to add meta tag element on Iframe parent head element, I had tried

**window.parent.$('head').append('sometext');**

this one was working on the source file and iframe file in the same folder, but it was not working on the cross domain, it causes

**window.parent.$ is not a function** issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('head', window.parent.document).append("test")
```

you'll probably want to use `.data()` instead of `.append()` though http://api.jquery.com/data/

The second argument of `$()` is the search context, default is `document`.

Comment: I have tried this one also, and I got **Permission denied to access property 'document' ** issue